# add_editor_style not working

Tags: theme-development

I created a style sheet

> editor-style.css

I want to load this css file using add_editor_style() function,

In my functions.php

```
function my_theme_add_editor_styles() {
    add_editor_style( 'css/editor-style.css' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_add_editor_styles' );
```

I also tried this solution

[add_editor_style is not loading in frontend. Any solution?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87256/add-editor-style-is-not-loading-in-frontend-any-solution)

Comment: Why does the file have two .css extensions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't need an action to add an editor style. Simple add the following anywhere in your functions.php:

```
add_editor_style('css/editor-style.css');
```

Comment: Thanks much!  The WordPress Codex suggests to do it the way @Relax tried.  Removing the function and action stuff worked great.

Answer (score 13):

You need to do two things (see additional add_theme_support):

```
add_theme_support( 'editor-styles' );
add_action('admin_init', 'el_add_editor_styles');

function el_add_editor_styles() {
    add_editor_style( get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/editor-style.css' );
}
```

Comment: sadly, this is the only answer that actually works. should be at the top and upvoted.

Comment: The reason their example is broken is that `add_editor_style` calls `add_theme_support( 'editor-styles' );` for you, but `admin_init` is too late to declare theme supports. So they should really recommend `add_editor_style` be hooked earlier, like `after_setup_theme` or something.

Comment: this answer is correct + the absolute path as specified in @Jake answer

Comment: This answer worked. The Accepted answer did not.

Comment: I updated the answer to include an absolute path to `editor-style.css`

Answer (score 3):

Use an absolute path for the stylesheet:

```
add_editor_style( get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/editor-style.css' );
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this is what worked

```
add_theme_support( 'editor-styles' );
add_editor_style( 'css/custom-editor-classes.css' );
```

I didn't need to put the absolute path or use add_action, but I did need to include add_theme_support. I'm guessing this may vary based on parent theme.